What's the SOTA sub-20MB model for language identification on texts between 1 and 5 words?
I looked into https://huggingface.co/papluca/xlm-roberta-base-language-detection?text=test, which claims an "average accuracy on the test set [of] 99.6%", but it often fails miserably on very short texts, e.g.:

bikini
bingo
man
test

What's the SOTA model for language identification on text between 1 and 5 words?

Constraints:

less than 20MB of disk space

supports as many of the following languages (esp. languages marked by an asterisk):

Danish

Dutch (Netherlands)

English (US & UK)

French*

German*

Italian*

Japanese*

Korean*

Norwegian

Portuguese (Brazil and EU)*

Russian*

Simplified Mandarin (China, Singapore)*

Spanish*

Swedish

Traditional Cantonese (Hong Kong)

Traditional Mandarin (Taiwan)




